# How do you mix Ruta types and regexes within a rule?

Tags: regex, ruta

I want to match street names and their house numbers that can also contain one character and a range of house numbers.

For Example:

```
Birkenstraße 22b
Birkenstraße 22b-23a
Birkenstraße 22b/23z
```

For this, I have the following rule in a ruta script:

```
(Street PERIOD? ((NUM "b"? (("/"|"-") NUM "b"?)?) {-> MARK(HouseNumber)}));
```

`"b"` is the place I want to match all characters, like in a regex with `[a-zA-Z]`. But I have tried to replace `"b"` with `"[a-zA-Z]"` and no HouseNumber was recognized at all. Whereas with `"b"` I can recognize the first part of the streets `Birkenstraße 22b` in my examples.

How can I mix this regular expression within a rule in UIMA Ruta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared a type and assigned it like this at the begin of my script:

```
DECLARE CHARS;
W{REGEXP("[a-zA-Z]") -> MARK(CHARS)};
```

After that, I added the type `CHARS` to my rule like this and it worked:

```
(Street PERIOD? ((NUM CHARS? (("/"|"-") NUM CHARS?)?) {-> MARK(HouseNumber)}));
```